# Network service account not inherited in ACL

Tags: iis-7, permissions, acl, inheritance

I have a problem with files that are being moved into a folder that is set to replace permissions on child objects for the Network Service account. The process is that a media file is uploaded to a website, and is encoded by a piece of software. This moves the file to a folder but for some reason the files that get moved there don't inherit the Network Service account in security permissions. If I manually move a file into the folder the permission is inherited. I have used the effective permissions tool to check the Network Service account security permissions on the parent folder but this shows that there is nothing overriding it - the account has full permissions.

Can try and supply more info if required, but any answers grealty appreciated!